# I accidentally xkilled the terminal that was running an upgrade, now what?

Tags: upgrade

I was upgrading my 12.04 to 12.10 today with terminal;

And my Thunderbird stopped working. I opened the terminal and opened xkill, but I unfortunately clicked on terminal by a mistake.

Now my computer says that 12.04 installed; (it was setting up the packages when that happened) and don't see 12.10 when I say upgrade.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
update-manager -d
```

Comment: I already did it.

Comment: Try this command : sudo dpkg --clear-avail && sudo apt-get update

It should clear your cache...